# greased/smeared/smudged in/into/with mustard

Tags: word-choice, word-request

He opened the door with his elbow as his hands were greased/smeared/smudged in/into/with mustard.

Could you please help me with what is possible here? Also, are there better options than "greased", "smeared", and "smudged"?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't suggest any of the above.

**Greased** suggests that the mustard was intended to enable him to carry out some action with oily hands.

**Smeared** is possible although it suggests that liberal amounts of mustard had been plastered across his hands, possibly deliberately.

**Smudged** doesn't work. Writing or images on paper or similar are smudged by water spills or by dirty hands.

Most people would simply say: **His hands were covered in mustard.** Or **He had (a lot of) mustard on his hands.**

Comment: Sticky with mustard?